# reading unix timestamp with sqlite3

Tags: sqlite

In an sqlite3 database, I am storing date and time as unix timestamps. Examples of unix timestamp we can find on our database: `1457600307000, 1457600109000, 1457599991000`.

When executing the following query:

```
SELECT datetime(my_date, 'unixepoch') as last_update 
FROM my_table;
```

the results are not what we expect. the date we are getting from executing that query is: `-1413-03-01 13:07:12`

when we would actually expect a date and time from `March / April 2016`.

Is there anyway I can `sqlite3` to read the timestamps correctly?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is difference between number of **seconds** from start of epoch and number of **miliseconds**. Divide by 1000:

```
SELECT my_date, datetime(my_date/1000, 'unixepoch') as last_update 
FROM my_table;
```

<kbd>**[`SqlFiddleDemo`](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!5/2a7b1/3/0)**</kbd>

Output:

```
╔════════════════╦═════════════════════╗
║    my_date     ║     last_update     ║
╠════════════════╬═════════════════════╣
║ 1457600307000  ║ 2016-03-10 08:58:27 ║
║ 1457600109000  ║ 2016-03-10 08:55:09 ║
║ 1457599991000  ║ 2016-03-10 08:53:11 ║
╚════════════════╩═════════════════════╝
```

> *when we would actually expect a date and time from March / April 2016.*

It looks like it is in range.